# Pandas Selection By Label

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I cannot understand what the following operation does by loc operator. This screenshot is taken from the pandas official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).
The original dataframe is in the 2nd screenshot .

[image: Problem]

[image: Original Dataframe]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.
I invite you to read the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. And then, to improve your post with a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your particular problem, so that we can help faster. And to answer your question, `.loc()` will here select only the columns where the number in the first row, indexed as `a`, is positive, hence you only get column `A` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a good thing to start decomposing the code, just like you decomposed math problems into simpler pieces at school, to understand the behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe construction
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4),
                  index=list('abcdef'),
                  columns=list('ABCD'))

# Selection of the row indexed as 'a' using .loc():
df1.loc['a']

# Selection of the row indexed as 'a' using .loc() 
# where elements in this rows are strictly positive:
df1.loc['a'] > 0

# Selection of all entire columns where the elements
# in the row indexed as 'a' are strictly positive:
df1.loc[:, df1.loc['a'] > 0]

# Whole dataframe:
df1
```

Warning, as the [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) is build with [random numbers](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html), you will almost never get the same results than the one in the documentation.